# Como tratar caractere reservado em um arquivo .ini no php?

Tags: php, string

Tenho um arquivo `.ini` onde guardo algumas informações fora da árvore de diretórios do site, acontece que em uma senha tenho caracteres especiais.

No momento em que o php pega esse conteúdo ele dá problema, a impressão que tenho é que ele pensa que é uma variável.

Segue um exemplo hipotético:

No arquivo `ini`:

```
[config]
pwd=123456!@#$%
```

No arquivo php depois de ler o `ini`:

```
...
leu o ini
$pwd = $Arquivo["config"]["pwd"];
$email_pwd = $pwd;
```

Como o conteúdo de `"pwd"` la no `ini` tem caractere `$`, imagino que ele entenda que é uma variável, quando na verdade o `$` faz parte da `string`.

Eu tentei colocar entre aspas duplas mas não funciona:

```
$email_pwd = "$pwd";
```

Se eu colocar a string literal com aspas simples ele aceita:

```
$email_pwd = '123456!@#$%';
```

Como contornar essa situação pra manter a senha no arquivo `ini`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#refsect1-function.parse-ini-file-notes

> If a value in the ini file contains any non-alphanumeric characters it needs to be enclosed in double-quotes (").

Você precisa adicionar o valor dentro de aspas duplas.

```
[config]
pwd = "123456!@#$%"
```

**Update**

O arquivo `.ini` pode possuir apóstrofos dentro de um valor de string, apenas ele acaba ignorando eles:

```
key="teste " aspas " duplas"
```

Saída:

```
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(18) "teste aspas duplas"
}
```

Para interpretar as aspas, pode ser feito de duas formas.

**Escapando a string:**

```
key="\"aspas duplas\""
```

Código em execução: https://3v4l.org/1FAla

**INI_SCANNER_RAW**

Arquivo `.ini` sem utilizar escape

```
key=""aspas duplas""
```

Utilize a flag `INI_SCANNER_RAW`

```
parse_ini($string , false , INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

Código em execução: https://3v4l.org/Z8YRb

Para ambos os casos, a saída é a mesma:

```
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(14) ""aspas duplas""
}
```

Comment: Eu li o link e entendi o seu exemplo, mas surgiu outra dúvida... e se na senha tivermos aspas duplas como escapar?, eu faria aspas dentro de aspas? Ex. "teste&'&"", veja que tenho aspas duplas e simples dentro da string.

Comment: @Marcelo eu atualizei a resposta